# Estimating the number of registered interaction designers in a given territory

Tags: sampling, dataset, survey

I plan to conduct a research study about Interaction Designers.

Prior to starting on sampling methods I am finding it very hard to get my hands on some demographics and statistics, e.g. How many people are registered to be employed as Interaction Designers, User Experience Designers etc. in a particular territory (UK in my case).

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your question, simply, how many people are employed as an interaction designer in the United Kingdom? or are you asking something more about sampling procedures?

Comment: Well this question is designed to help me develop my sampling method. But prior to that I want to have an idea about how many people are there in total with that job title in a given territory.

Comment: I haven't really looked into this, but one imagines that linkedin and specifically looking at the membership totals for UX UI groups on Linkedin would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The recent census (27/March/2011) in the UK had "full and specific job title" as personal question #34. So the Office for National Statistics must have information on this.

Comment: I did search statistics website but it is very generic:                  213 Info & Communication Technology

2131 IT strategy and planning prfsnals
2132 Software professionals

Comment: I have little experience with contacting the ONS, but if getting the data were important to me I would ask them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems of a national census is that it takes a long time to get all the data together so it may be a while until it appears but if you want census data try
https://www.census.ac.uk

Comment: This does not seem to have any data about number of people who work as either Interaction Designers or User Experience Designers